# Rainmeter Remove last space

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy, rainmeter

From the example, the name of the processor is returned but with a space at the end, how can I make it return a value without a space in the end?

```
[MeasureRun]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=RunCommand
Parameter=wmic cpu get Name
OutputType=ANSI
RegExpSubstitute=1
Substitute="Name.*#CRLF#":"","#CRLF#":""
ClipString=1
IfCondition=1
IfTrueAction=[!CommandMeasure MeasureRun "Run"]

[MeterResult]
Meter=String
MeasureName=MeasureRun
FontSize=14
FontColor=255,255,255,255
AntiAlias=1
Text=%1!
```

[image: Look at the image]

I think this can be done through regular expression, but I'm not strong at it.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Rahul Look https://i.imgur.com/kkctSsq.png, I think it's not very nice

Comment: _space at the end_ Which space are you talking about and where have you used the regex ?

Comment: In the Substitute line, there is a regex, I mean the space that remains in the returned string

Answer (score 0):

Just add another [**Substitute**](https://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/measures/general-options/substitute/#Substitute) in the substitution list to replace the occurence of one or more whitespaces from the end of the string (the pattern `"\s+$"`) with an empty string like below:

```
Substitute="Name.*#CRLF#":"","#CRLF#":"","\s+$":""
```